# Mailchimp Shortcode disappearing

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp, shortcode

I am using MailChimp for WP plugin to create a form and I have added the shortcode to my page by using Classic Mode to place it exactly where I want it to be.

However, although it seems to show fine immediately after placing it, it does end up disappearing after a very short while. The shortcode itself that I have place appears to be no longer there anymore. Am I doing something wrong?

I am using the latest version of WordPress and the latest version of the plugin.

I'm using Jupiter theme, and I am adding the shortcode [mcw4wp_form] through Visual Composer which gives you the option to have Classic Mode in which you can write your custom code.

Comment: It may be possible after sone time with jquery that div is getting the css of hide that element.. check with firebug

Comment: What do you mean "Classic Mode"? When you say its disappearing, I assume you mean the actual shortcode e.g. `[mcw4wp_form]`? Its impossible for us to know whats happening with so little information. Are you using a custom theme? Have you tried activating one of WPs default themes and disabling your plugins to see if any of those are causing the issue?

Comment: @FluffyKitten I'm sorry for not providing enough information. I'm using Jupiter theme, and I am adding the shortcode that you have mentioned above through Visual Composer which gives you the option to have Classic Mode in which you can write your custom code, that is what I meant. However it does end up disappearing at times. So far it is still on, but I am still struggling with working with this plugin. For example for now, whenever I click on signup it takes me to a 404 page not found instead of showing me successful signup message.

Comment: @FluffyKitten if you would like to take a further look I would disable coming soon mode if that will help. I really appreciate your help on this matter.

Comment: @FluffyKitten when I click sign up, it takes me to a page that does not exist even though I have written in the plugin settings that there must not be any redirections. I do not get the message that says I have successfully signed up or anything, however I do get an email asking me to confirm subscription.

Comment: Ah I see. I don't use Visual Composer so I didn't know what Classic Mode meant. The reason you get an email to confirm subscription instead of a signup is that you must have two-step authentication turned on (which is actually good practice). As for the other problems, its hard to say without seeing your setup. Have you checked your API keys etc? FYI you should update your question with any additional information, as other people may not see it in the comments.

Comment: The email is understandable and is quite nice, however I cannot understand why it redirects me to a page that doesn't exist. I will open the website so you can have a look in there for yourself. Again, I really appreciate your time and help! The link to the website is - www.generationp.com and the sign up button is found almost at the very end of the page. Please let me know what you think the problem is or what I am doing wrong! @FluffyKitten

Comment: I took a look at your site but there's not much I can tell from the site itself, we can't even see what url is causing the 404 error. Can you see whats triggering the 404 error in the server logs? If not, you could try a plugin like [404 Error Logger](https://wordpress.org/plugins/404-error-logger/) and then check where that url is included, and temporarily turning off the "double opt in" option. Also, try using a default WP theme and disabling other plugins like I suggested before, to see if something else is affecting how it works.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I will try the 404 plugin, hopefully it works. Thank you so much for your help! I hope it works out :(!